# How can I cancel a transaction once I read documents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I am trying to build a game where I remove the balance of 2 users at the same time only if they have enough gold there. Once I get all documents (user's balances), I 'm doing some logic and checking that the new balance will not be < 0:

```js
const removeGamglingBalanceFor2Users = (
    user1, user2, amount, resolve, reject,
) => {
  const userDocRef1 = db.collection(DB_USERS).doc(user1.id);
  const userDocRef2 = db.collection(DB_USERS).doc(user2.id);
  db.runTransaction(
      (t) => t.getAll(userDocRef1, userDocRef2).then((docs) => {
        const balances = [];
        docs.forEach((doc) => {
          balances.push(doc.data()[FIELD_BALANCE] - amount);
        });

        if (Math.min(...balances) < 0){
          reject(INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS);
          t.rollback();
          return;
        }

        [userDocRef1, userDocRef2].forEach((doc) => {
          t.update(doc,
              { [FIELD_BALANCE]: FieldValue.increment(-amount) });
        });
      }),
  ).then(() => {
    resolve();
  }).catch((err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
};
```

This code execute server side with admin SDK and a service account.

Even when the condition `Math.min(...balances) < 0)` is true, it rejects the promise but it's not caught in the reject block. In addition, it keeps running and remove the balance.

Instead of `t.rollback()` I tried `t.abort()` but it's not known as a function..

- Is there a way to stop the transaction?
- Is it a good way to remove balances from transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `throw INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` instead of `reject(INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS)`

```js
const removeGamglingBalanceFor2Users = (
    user1, user2, amount, resolve, reject,
) => {
  const userDocRef1 = db.collection(DB_USERS).doc(user1.id);
  const userDocRef2 = db.collection(DB_USERS).doc(user2.id);
  db.runTransaction(
      (t) => t.getAll(userDocRef1, userDocRef2).then((docs) => {
        const balances = docs.map(doc => doc.data()[FIELD_BALANCE] - amount)
        
        if (Math.min(...balances) < 0)
          throw INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS

        [userDocRef1, userDocRef2].forEach((doc) => {
          t.update(doc,
              { [FIELD_BALANCE]: FieldValue.increment(-amount) });
        });
      })
  )
  .then(() => resolve())
  .catch(reject);
};
```

Comment: You're right throw is working perfectly!
However, I am wondering if I don't need to abort something regarding the transaction?

Comment: @Elsha You're not updating anything before throwing an error, so it's not needed

Comment: @Elsha As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions), "Transactions never partially apply writes. All writes execute at the end of a successful transaction.... A failed transaction returns an error and does not write anything to the database. You do not need to roll back the transaction; Cloud Firestore does this automatically."